# LIKE mysql query order by search word

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have two table

```
create table crm_location_site (loc_name varchar(100),loc_id int(11) );
insert into crm_location_site values 
('Dubai Marina',11),
('Marina Residance',12),
('Jumera Marina',13)
create table crm_subloc (sub_sub_loc varchar(100),sub_loc_id int(11) );
insert into crm_subloc values 
('Ora Marina',11),
('Grand Ora Marina',12)
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT loc_id as id,loc_name as name,'loc' as tbl 
FROM crm_location_site
WHERE TRIM(loc_name) LIKE '%M%' 
UNION
SELECT sub_loc_id as id,sub_sub_loc as name,'subloc' as tbl 
FROM crm_subloc
WHERE TRIM(sub_sub_loc) LIKE '%M%'
```

This query give me

```
Dubai Marina
Marina Residance
Jumera marina
```

I want to show matched with starting in top.

Like in this order

```
Marina Residance
Dubai Marina
Jumera marina
```

Here is a simple fiddle[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bb47/2)

Comment: What is the value of $term ?

Comment: You need to better describe what you want. This is too difficult to understand : `I want to show matched with starting in top.like`

Comment: Could you precise what you exactly need -> bette sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad8331

Comment: I need to change order of display result...$term is M

Comment: You only want the 2 first values ?

Comment: NO I want to display all but in order of matched characters...

Comment: @Muhammad "Marina Residance" starts with "M". so displays first?

Comment: yes,its like that....if i type 'MA' then also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT loc_id as id,loc_name as name,'loc' as tbl 
    FROM crm_location_site
    WHERE TRIM(loc_name) LIKE '%M%' 
    UNION
    SELECT sub_loc_id as id,sub_sub_loc as name,'subloc' as tbl 
    FROM crm_subloc
    WHERE TRIM(sub_sub_loc) LIKE '%M%'
) x
ORDER BY POSITION('M' in name);
```

### FYI

**SORT BY name which has most repeated**

```
ORDER BY (LENGTH(name) - LENGTH(REPLACE('M', '', name))) / LENGTH('M') DESC;
```

Comment: @Muhammad *"yes,its like that....if i type 'MA' then also"* `POSITION` allows more than one character. like `ORDER BY POSITION('Ma' in name)`

Comment: @Muhammad Thank you for accepting. I have updated. check out FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that

```
|ID |   NAME             |TBL|
|12 |   Marina Residance |loc|
|11 |   Dubai Marina     |loc|
|13 |   Jumera Marina    |  loc|
|11 |   Ora Marina       |subloc|
|12 |   Grand Ora Marina |subloc|
```

---

```
SELECT loc_id AS id,loc_name AS name,'loc' AS tbl
FROM crm_location_site
WHERE TRIM(loc_name) LIKE 'M%'
UNION 
SELECT sub_loc_id AS id,sub_sub_loc AS name,'subloc' AS tbl
FROM crm_subloc
WHERE TRIM(sub_sub_loc) LIKE 'M%'
UNION  
SELECT loc_id AS id,loc_name AS name,'loc' AS tbl
FROM crm_location_site
WHERE TRIM(loc_name) LIKE '%M%'
UNION 
SELECT sub_loc_id AS id,sub_sub_loc AS name,'subloc' AS tbl
FROM crm_subloc
WHERE TRIM(sub_sub_loc) LIKE '%M%'
```

[sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad8331/8)

Comment: why you have UNION again and again?

Comment: the idea would be as soon as the field begin with the researched element, please show first

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad8331/11

```
SELECT loc_id as id,loc_name as name,'loc' as tbl 
FROM crm_location_site
WHERE TRIM(loc_name) LIKE '%M%' 
UNION
SELECT sub_loc_id as id,sub_sub_loc as name,'subloc' as tbl 
FROM crm_subloc
WHERE TRIM(sub_sub_loc) LIKE '%M%'
ORDER BY POSITION('M' in name)
```

OR http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad8331/14

```
SELECT loc_id as id,loc_name as name,'loc' as tbl 
FROM crm_location_site
WHERE TRIM(loc_name) LIKE '%M%' 
UNION
SELECT sub_loc_id as id,sub_sub_loc as name,'subloc' as tbl 
FROM crm_subloc
WHERE TRIM(sub_sub_loc) LIKE '%M%'
ORDER BY IF (name LIKE 'M%', 0, 1)
```